# second Activity to drawer fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

### Second Activity to drawer fragment where drawer extend Activity

[image]

I have some issue..in navigate **activity2** to fragment of **Activity1**

I have try this code..

```
  Fragment3 f3 = new Fragment3();
    f3.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, f3).commit();
```

it work but fragment3 not show in drawer....It overwrite on **Activity2**

I want fragment3 in drawer after navigate....

Comment: where does this container located android.R.id.content ?

Comment: no, i  meant where have you put the android.R.id.content ?  which activity ?

Comment: in first activity where fragment 3 is awailable

Comment: sry its default view .... i just copy past this code

Comment: @DavidJhons  any othor solution ..please tell me

Comment: you want to navigate from activity 1 to activity 2 and then, fragment 1 must be appear on the activity 2 , am i right ?

Comment: activity2 ==> activity1(fragment 3)

Comment: @DavidJhons  same like yo said

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74250/discussion-between-vishal-patel-and-davidjhons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ,

1. Navigate from activity1 to activity 2

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
   startActivity(intent );
   ```
2. Load fragment 1 on the activity2's container

   ```
   Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
   f1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .add(android.R.id.content, f1).commit();
   ```